# GNU GRUB screen no longers loads Ubuntu OS

Tags: boot, grub2

I was working fine with Ubuntu but one day when I restart it because it freeze the Lap return to the GNU GRUB screen (the purple one) where there's only 3 options: Ubuntu / Advanced option for Ubuntu / System setup. 
When I hit Ubuntu the screen freezes in the purple screen like if its loading but it can stay like that for hours. 
I havent make my backup so, what are the commands to recover my info?